# Bootstrap modal inside container with styles associated on hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal inside a container that has styles associated on hover. When the modal opens, the on hover styles are applied like if the modal wasn't open. Here is an example this problem:

http://www.bootply.com/E6jsnaJTOP

In my code I can't move the modal outside the container, because there are several containers, each one with a unique modal.

How can I prevent the on hover styles from being applied when the modal is open?

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct if it resolved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can key off the fact that when the modal is open the `<body>` element has the `modal-open` class.

```
body:not(.modal-open) #block_1:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```